# Limit filter (only: :index) when filtering with a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use debugger after an action has been parsed, so I can have access to the **response object** and inspect it.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  after_action do |controller|
    debugger
  end, only: :index
```

It works if I don't use the **", only: :index"** part.

But I wonder, is it possible to limit the filter just to the **index action**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the args before the block this way:

```
after_action(only: :index) do |controller|
  debugger
end
```